Fastest way to solve many systems of integral equations using python
I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like the following:
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Probability  
1         1/1/2023       3               0.02167131     
1         1/1/2023       4               0.17349148     
1         1/1/2023       6               0.08438952     
1         1/1/2023       8               0.04143787     
1         1/1/2023       9               0.02589056
1         1/1/2023       1               0.03866752     
1         1/1/2023       10              0.0461553     
1         1/1/2023       45              0.09212758
1         1/1/2023       23              0.10879326      
1         1/1/2023       102             0.186921      
1         1/1/2023       75              0.02990676      
1         1/1/2023       27              0.02731904      
1         1/1/2023       15              0.06020158      
1         1/1/2023       29              0.06302721                         
3         17/4/2022      5               0.2     
3         17/4/2022      2               0.1     
3         17/4/2022      3               0.55     
3         17/4/2022      4               0.15     

with the property that the probability of each student sums to 1 for each race. And I would like to generate a new column by solving a system of highly nonlinear integral eequation for each race using the following method:

Define the following function using integrals

import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.stats import norm
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def integrandforpi_i(xi, ti, *theta):
  prod = 1
  for t in theta:
    prod = prod * (1 - norm.cdf(xi - t))
  return prod * norm.pdf(xi - ti)

def pi_i(ti, *theta):
  return integrate.quad(integrandforpi_i, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(ti, *theta))[0]

i.e. we define the function $\pi_i$ (the probability for student $i$) to be
$$\pi_i=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{j\not=i}(1-\Phi(x_i-\theta_j))\phi(x_i-\theta_i)\,dx_i.$$
where $\phi, \Phi$ are the probability density function and cumulative density function of ths standard normal variable respsectively, and the product is taken over the students in the same race who is not student $i$.

for each Race_ID, the value for each Student_ID in the new column is given by solving a system of nonlinear equations using least_squares in scipy.optimize as follows:

For example, for race 1, there are 14 students in the race and we will have to solve the following system of 14 nonlinear equations and we restrict the bound in between -2 and 2:
def equations(params):
    t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14 = params
    return (pi_i(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.02167131,
            pi_i(t2,t1,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.17349148,
            pi_i(t3,t2,t1,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.08438952,
            pi_i(t4,t2,t3,t1,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.04143787,
            pi_i(t5,t2,t3,t4,t1,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.02589056,
            pi_i(t6,t2,t3,t4,t5,t1,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.03866752,
            pi_i(t7,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t1,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.0461553,
            pi_i(t8,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t1,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.09212758,
            pi_i(t9,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t1,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.10879326,
            pi_i(t10,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t1,t11,t12,t13,t14) - 0.186921,
            pi_i(t11,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t1,t12,t13,t14) - 0.02990676,
            pi_i(t12,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t1,t13,t14) - 0.02731904,
            pi_i(t13,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t1,t14) - 0.06020158,
            pi_i(t14,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t13,t14,t1) - 0.06302721)

res = least_squares(equations, (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), bounds = ((-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2), (2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)))

t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14 = res.x

Solving gives t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14 = [1.38473533 0.25616609 0.6935956  1.07314877 1.30201502 1.10781642 1.01839475 0.64349646 0.54630158 0.20719836 1.23347391 1.27642131 0.879412   0.83338882]
Similarly, for race 2, there are 4 students competing and we will have to solve the following system of 4 nonlinear equations:
def equations(params):
    t1,t2,t3,t4 = params
    return (pi_i(t1,t2,t3,t4) - 0.2,
            pi_i(t2,t1,t3,t4) - 0.1,
            pi_i(t3,t2,t1,t4) - 0.55,
            pi_i(t4,t2,t3,t1) - 0.15)

res = least_squares(equations, (1,1,1,1), bounds = ((-2,-2,-2,-2), (2,2,2,2)))

t1,t2,t3,t4 = res.x

which gives t1,t2,t3,t4 = [0.9209873  1.37615468 0.12293934 1.11735818].
Hence the desired outcome looks like
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Probability    new_column
1         1/1/2023       3               0.02167131     1.38473533
1         1/1/2023       4               0.17349148     0.25616609
1         1/1/2023       6               0.08438952     0.6935956
1         1/1/2023       8               0.04143787     1.07314877
1         1/1/2023       9               0.02589056     1.30201502
1         1/1/2023       1               0.03866752     1.10781642
1         1/1/2023       10              0.0461553      1.01839475
1         1/1/2023       45              0.09212758     0.64349646
1         1/1/2023       23              0.10879326     0.54630158
1         1/1/2023       102             0.186921       0.20719836
1         1/1/2023       75              0.02990676     1.23347391
1         1/1/2023       27              0.02731904     1.27642131 
1         1/1/2023       15              0.06020158     0.879412 
1         1/1/2023       29              0.06302721     0.83338882                    
3         17/4/2022      5               0.2            0.9209873
3         17/4/2022      2               0.1            1.37615468
3         17/4/2022      3               0.55           0.12293934
3         17/4/2022      4               0.15           1.11735818

And here is my code:
def change_order(parameters, i):
    return [parameters[i]] + parameters[0:i] + parameters[i+1:]

def system(parameters, t):
    parameters = parameters.tolist()
    values = np.full(len(t), np.nan)
    for i in range(len(parameters)):
        parameters = change_order(parameters, i)
        values[i] = pi_i(*parameters) - t[i]
    return values

def solver(x):
    t = x["Probability"].values
    u = np.ones_like(t)
    solution = optimize.least_squares(system, u, bounds=[-2*u, 2*u], args=(t,))
    return solution.x

data["new_column"] = data.groupby("Race_ID").apply(solver, include_groups=False).explode().values

The code works fine, but it is incredibly slow. It takes about 6-10 mins for 1 race and I have about 10000 races to compute. I have tried other optimization methods in scipy such as conjugate gradient method fmin_cg and fsolve. However it's still very slow.
So my question is, is there any way to speed up the code? (I need to get it down to 1 minute per race) I see there are many optimization libraries out there such as ortools from Google but I haven't checked them out. Few things that might be useful:

I don't really need the bound to be $[-2,2]$. It's basically arbitrary since it is easy to see that if $(\theta_i)_i$ is a solution then so is $(\theta_i + a)_i$ for any constant $a$.

I don't really need extreme precision. scipy computes the thetas up to 8 decimal points but for my purpose 4 decimal points suffice.



Also posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4954782/quickly-solving-a-system-of-integral-equations-using-numerical-methods-analytic where an answer has been given. I guess it would finish the story off if not for the strange error the OP gets when trying to run my code, an error that I cannot reproduce on my PC or anywhere else. If somebody can reproduce that error or has any idea where it might come from, both I and OP would be most grateful (my Python programming is pretty basic, so for a professional it should be easy to see what might go wrong with it)

The issue was resolved. It was a bug in google colab (I expected Google to me better than Microsoft, but, apparently, it isn't). However, if someone can create an even faster code than mine, it would be interesting to see :-)
